# Reverse Proxy for domain-name

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup Apache as a reverse proxy for a domain-name. It should redirect to an application running on a Apache Tomcat server

i'm using the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/application/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/application/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I go to http://sub.domain.com it results in an endless loop of http redirects. It also automatically adds the subdirectory to the url. http://sub.domain.com changes in http://sub.domain.com/application/

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to disable `ProxyPreserveHost` as it keeps passing the old host, which unless you have a good reason to do so, isn't recommended.

Comment: When i disable ProxyPreserveHost something causes the application to only show me the login page. No matter what address I visit it always shows the login page. This could be an error in the application.

Comment: That it could be... the other thing I was going to recommend is putting a line like this: `ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/ !` to see if stopping the redirect when you actually get to the page helps..

Comment: You may also want to use the `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` to ensure the cookies get the right domain in them for your login.

Comment: I fixed it by just deploying my application in tomcat's root so i don't have the issues with the subdirectories. But thanks for the help!